# How to include ID in JSON with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot, I have a `User` class, and a `UserRepository` interface.

When I fetch users from the REST API, it returns the list as `JSON+HAL` format containing all users with their attributes excepted the `id` which is the primary key, and well that's the most important since I want to use it in URLs to edit users...

The ID attribute is declared as below in the `User` class.

```
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

And here is the very standard repository not even customized.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users")
  public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Do I need to tweak something to include the `id` in the user list ?

It's a blackbox, I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` attribute is not exposed by default.

You need to use the `exposeIdsFor` method on `RepositoryRestConfiguration`

Something like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void repositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(User.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get MyConfiguration used/picked up?

Comment: And... where do you get RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration from?